# Return false /stop propagation from nested callback

Tags: javascript, callback, jquery-callback

I have seen this question asked before, but have had no luck implementing the solutions in my own work. The page continues to jump to the top.

first I have a listener:

```
$('.edit-description').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   contentContainer = $('#description');
   openEditor(contentContainer);
   return false;
});
```

then my openEditor function with the contained callback:

```
function openEditor(contentContainer){

    var contentType=contentContainer.data('value');
    getRecentEdits(markid, entityType, contentType, function(data){

        if (editArea){
            hiddenContentArea.show();
            editArea.hide();
        }
        hiddenContentArea=contentContainer;
        contentContainer.hide();
        editArea =  $('<div class="edit-container" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">' +
                        '       <textarea class="form-control js-auto-size" style="margin-bottom:5px;">'+ data[0].content+
                        '       </textarea>' +
                        '       <a class="right leave-editor"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>Leave Editor</a>'+
                        '       <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-custom-green submit-edit pull-right right " style="color:#fff;padding-top:5px; background-color: #3D8A11; border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Submit</button>'+
                        '</div>');
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           /** var fileLink = '<a href="#">'+data[i].username+'</a>';
            editArea.prepend(fileLink);**/
            console.log(data[i]);
        }

        var parent=contentContainer.parents("p");
        parent.after(editArea);
        $('textarea.js-auto-size').textareaAutoSize();

        if (contentType==1){
            $('.edit-container').prepend('<div style="color:red;">Note: &nbsp;The description area should contain only facts. Opinions and reviews can be posted on the board below.</div>');
        }

        return false;
        });
    return false;
}
```

and this gets called from within:

```
function getRecentEdits(id, entityType, contentType, callback){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_recent_edits.php",
    data: {id: id, entity_type:entityType, content_type:contentType},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
        return false;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("At this time, you could not be added to the list of followers of this location. There was likely a technical difficulty that will fix itself if you try again a bit later. Thanks!");
        alert(data['message'], data['success']);
    }
});
return false;
}
```

As you can see, I have put a 'return false everywhere conceivably possible.

Sorry for the exorbitant amounts of code. Didn't see any solution to posting it all.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `.preventDefault()` instead of `stopPropagation()`. And that `return false` right in the click handler should suffice, and should work unless one of the called functions throws (which would not surprise me given the complete lack of local variable declarations in your code).

Comment: What is the problem though? You've shown your attempt at a solution, but we don't know what the problem is. Returning `false` from every function probably isn't the right way to go about things. Are you simply trying to stop the click event from scrolling the user to the top of the page? Try `e.preventDefault()` right at the beginning of the click handler.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks... Sorry, left out my variable declarations. Using .preventDefault worked. I need to review the difference between that and return false.